# MATLAB: How to tabulate structs with same fields

Tags: arrays, excel, matlab

I have use a 428×1 cell array called data

```
data = {[1×1 struct]
        [1×1 struct]
        ....
        [1x1 struct]}
```

These struct all have the same structure

```
data {2,1}

>>struct with fields

         additional_model_information: 'H Series,S3150-S0-AW-04-02-C-F421,'
 ceiling_fan_size_diameters_in_inches: '60'
      airflow_efficiency_cfm_watt_low: '727'
     airflow_efficiency_cfm_watt_high: '392'
```

The structure fields are the same for all 428 cells, and the fields values change in each struct.

How could i create a table that puts all of the structs together so that it shows all of the field values for each field? Pehaps using a nested for loop?

I eventually want to export this data to excel.

Comment: What version of Matlab are you using? Do you actually want this data in a `table`, or will a `cell array` work as long as you can export to Excel?

Comment: MATLAB R2017a. As long as i can export to Excel @Wolfie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you've got your nx1 cell array of structs, `data`. This method doesn't assume you have 4 fields in your data or any knowledge of what they are called. You could even use it with structs with different fieldnames if you included some `try`/`catch` logic.

---

You can get the field names of a representative struct using `fieldnames`

```
fnames = fieldnames(data{1});
```

Then set up some output cell array `out` of the correct size

```
out = cell(numel(fnames), numel(data));
```

Then use nested loops to **1.** loop through items in `data` and **2.** loop through field names.

```
for n = 1:numel(data)
    for field = 1:numel(fnames)
        temp = data{n};
        out{field, n} = temp.(fnames{field});
    end
end
```

Finally, append the field names as the first column

```
out = [fnames, out];
```

And write the cell array to your Excel file

```
%        File location,      cell array,  sheet,  cell
xlswrite('C:\...\test.xlsx', out,         1,      'A1');
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm getting this responce: Reference to non-existent field 'additional_model_information'.

Error in Untitled (line 8)
        out{field, n} = temp.(fnames{field});

Comment: That means the struct in `data{n}` doesn't contain the field `additional_model_information`... try surrounding the `out{field, n}` line in a `try; out{field, n} = temp.(fnames{field});
; catch; end;`. You will end up with an empty cell element where you expect that field, but it will skip the error.

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked perfectly well. I've just reliased that the struct in data {n} contains number, text and floating_timestamp

Comment: Ah glad I could help... consider marking this answer as accepted if it solved your problem :)

Comment: I will. Thank you

Comment: say for instance data {n} above was downloaded from one URL. If now you want to download from more than one URL (a list of URLs for instance), and still apply the above answer to the newly downloaded data, How do i go about?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking, as your original question had nothing to do with downloading data from URLs... perhaps mark this answer as accepted and ask another question with this new problem.

Comment: I've been trying to find that option to mark my question answered. Been struggling to find it. Even now.

Comment: It is the green/white tick mark underneath the voting arrows (top left of the answer), thank you. If you clarify your follow up question or ask it in a new question, I'll try and help

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
T = cell(length(data) , 4);
for k = 1 : length(data)
   T(k , :) = {data{k}.additional_model_information , ...
               data{k}.ceiling_fan_size_diameters_in_inches, ...
               data{k}.airflow_efficiency_cfm_watt_low, ...
               data{k}.airflow_efficiency_cfm_watt_high};
end
```

Then you can use `xlswrite` to export to excel.